# Witcher 3: Where is Alcohol/Dwarven Spirit stored in inventory?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I can't find the number of strong alcohol bottles in the inventory to replenish the potion after meditation. Are they shown in some other place?

Answer (score 3):

You can find them in alchemy ingredients tab.